# XML schema XSD file error

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have the below example XML that I want to validate against the below schema.  I get an error regarding extraImages.  The error is:

> Error 3033: Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}sequence': The
>   content is not valid. Expected is (annotation?, (element | group |
>   choice | sequence | any)*).

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?  When I have the extraImages complex type in a separate schema, it works, but does not work when I add it to the products schema.

```
<products>
<product>
<productImageURL>imgp9241.jpg</productImageURL>
<productDescription>blah blah blah</productDescription>
<productName>Test Extra</productName>
<extraImages>
<extraImages>
<fileName>textextra.jpg</fileName>
<sequence>10</sequence>
</extraImages>
<extraImages>
<fileName>textextra.jpg</fileName>
<sequence>10</sequence>
</extraImages>
</extraImages>
</product>
</products>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsd:element name="products">
   <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="product" minOccurs = "1" maxOccurs="1" type="productType"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

    <xsd:complexType name="productType">
       <xsd:sequence>

           <xsd:element name="productImageURL">
              <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:minLength value="0" />
                    <xsd:maxLength value="450" />
                    <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse" /> 
                </xsd:restriction>
              </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>

           <xsd:element name="productDescription">
              <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                    <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse"/> 
                </xsd:restriction>
              </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>

           <xsd:element name="productName">
              <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                    <xsd:maxLength value="150"/>
                    <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse"/> 
                </xsd:restriction>
              </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>


            <xsd:element name="extraImages">
               <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:sequence>
                     <xsd:element name="extraImage" minOccurs = "1" maxOccurs="100" type="imgType"/>
                  </xsd:sequence>
               </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>

                <xsd:complexType name="imgType">
                   <xsd:sequence>

                         <xsd:element name="fileName">
                          <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:maxLength value="25"/>
                                <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse"/> 
                            </xsd:restriction>
                          </xsd:simpleType>
                        </xsd:element>

                        <xsd:element name="sequence" type="xsd:integer" default="0"/>

                   </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>          


       </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>  

</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message tells you that the **XSD** is invalid. You can't have a **named** type nested inside anything else other than a *schema* or *redefine*.

The corrected XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="products">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="product" minOccurs = "1" maxOccurs="1" type="productType"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:complexType name="productType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="productImageURL">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:minLength value="0"/>
                        <xsd:maxLength value="450"/>
                        <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="productDescription">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                        <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="productName">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                        <xsd:maxLength value="150"/>
                        <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="extraImages">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="extraImage" minOccurs = "1" maxOccurs="100" type="imgType"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="imgType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="fileName">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:maxLength value="25"/>
                        <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="sequence" type="xsd:integer" default="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

It shows this layout:

[image]

After fixing the XSD, you can try to validate the XML you've shown. When looking at its structure while comparing it with the XSD...

[image]

You can see that the ***extraImages***  **nested** within the extraImages should be without an `s`.

```
Error occurred while loading [], line 7 position 5
The element 'extraImages' has invalid child element 'extraImages'. List of possible elements expected: 'extraImage'.
```

Comment: thank you for such a comprehensive answer, love the diagrams!

Answer (score 0):

In the XSD, you are using two different elements: **extraImages** and **extraImage**

But in your XML, you are using **extraImages** twice instead of using extraImages and extraImage once each